# Magento - Use a grid as an input form

Tags: php, html, forms, magento, grid

I'm new to magento and my plan is to use input fields (for multiple columns and rows) in a grid and send their content via POST to the controller.

In my grid class (which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) I've added the input fields in the following way:

```
    $this->addColumn('name[]',
            array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Name'),
                    'index' => 'name',
                    'type'  => 'input',
                    'name'  => 'name[]'
    ));
```

Now I'm looking for an easy method to send the entered data to the controller (and to retrieve that data via $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost());

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento submits this grid using grid.js
You can override grid.js, capture all input values corresponding to checked rows and then submit the form.
Here you can put input field names and values.

```
this.formHiddens.update('');
new Insertion.Bottom(this.formHiddens, this.fieldTemplate.evaluate({name: fieldName, value: value}));
```